# Анимация CollectionView swift

Tags: swift

Всем привет подскажите как сделать смену картинки в collection view  как на картинке Что бы выбранный обьект был больше размером чем другие как бы выезжал немного в перед [image]

Comment: Единственная идея - вынести констрейнты на высоту и ширину картинки в код ячейки и в методе заполнения (куда вы передаёте изображение) добавить флаг `isSelected`. Если он равен `true`, то вы увеличиваете высоту и ширину на условные 20 единиц

Comment: И ещё одна идея: в методе, где вы возвращаете размер ячеек (метод `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`) смотреть на ячейку: если она находится в центре экрана, то вернуть ей размер чуть больше, чем у других. Тогда изображение автоматически увеличится, так как оно прижато констрейтами к краям (всё ведь верно?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать эту библиотеку - https://github.com/fahidattique55/FAPaginationLayout

Возможно, стоит поиграться с лейаутом и все будет как надо :)

Comment: Спасибо большое именно то что я искал